# Can I programmatically find all untagged resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

The Tag Editor in AWS's web console allows me to search for "All resource types" where a specific tag is not present. For example, I can list everything that is missing the tag "environment".

I'd like to run this as a periodic check, to enforce that no new untagged resources have been created. Some Boto code (running as a Lambda cron job) seems like a good fit. However, the Boto docs only show me how to look at a specific resource type (*e.g.* EC2 instances).

Is there any API for asking about tags in general? Or do I need to enumerate every resource type?

Comment: I left this here in case help someone https://github.com/llizamab/aws-tags-monitorization is a a csv and email report project with serverless framework to identify untagged resources. I made this because resourcegroupstaggingapi doesnt return resources who never has been tagged greetings

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just posting here if someone looks for the same question in the future.

AWS Resource Group offers features like this. You can access Resource Group in AWS console through https://console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/home. 
I didn't find how to use `--tag-filters` with unTagged value in CLI so used `jq` to filter out results.

Here is a sample command to get all resources without Environment Tag.

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "environment"} ]}) | not)'
```

Get Resource through `resourcegroupstaggingapi` reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html

For more information about Resource Group API, Please visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_GetResources.html

Comment: This does work (with a restriction). The API will not return resources that have never been tagged. It will only return them once they have had at least one tag in the past, even if they don't have tags anymore.

Answer (score 12):

You can use AWS Resource Groups from the console, per [this write-up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/find-resources-to-tag.html), to find resources that have an empty value for a tag.  To find resources that have a tag key but no tag value, choose (not tagged).
[image: AWS Resource Groups and Tag Editor]

If you are looking for automated alerting, consider using [AWS Config Rules](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/aws-config-rules/) and take a look at this [related blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-query-your-aws-resource-configuration-states-using-aws-config-and-amazon-athena/) as well.  In particular, there is a rule template called "required_tags" that checks for the presence of up to 5 tags. You can run more instances of the rule as needed, or modify the code.  Find links that that and other [rule templates here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/managed-rules-by-aws-config.html).

I also found a [nice blog](https://onica.com/blog/devops/using-aws-cli-to-find-untagged-instances/) that helps answer the question by using filtering when invoking service APIs via the CLI.

I also found that using AWS Config worked pretty well too.  Once AWS Config is setup for a particular AWS Region, you can submit an advanced query to find missing tags, like this one for a missing tag on EC2 resources:

```
SELECT
  resourceId,
  resourceType,
  configuration.instanceType,
  configuration.placement.tenancy,
  configuration.imageId,
  tags,
  availabilityZone
WHERE
  resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  AND tags.key NOT LIKE 'owner'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for tags in general. You have to do it for every service type. It is not that difficult. I have a Lambda that gets executed (through S3 PutObject / CloudTrail) which checks for the newly created instances and tags them if needed. It is very easy to extend it other types of AWS services since CloudTrail monitors most of the AWS services. But if you are looking to find all untagged resources, then you have to write a Boto script and query for tags for each service type.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is accepted but this could help:
Use AWS Resource Explorer (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resource-explorer/latest/userguide/using-search-query-syntax.html):

```
aws resource-explorer-2 search --query-string="tag:none -tag.key:aws* region eu-west-1" >untagged_resource.json
```

This overcome the restriction of the AWS Resource Group cli command which was mentioned above by @Anoop Philip

This service does not cost anything. https://aws.amazon.com/resourceexplorer/pricing/